# How can I implement a function to repeat a char in C?

Tags: c

I have this function which is giving me a hard time:

```
char * repeat_char(const char c, const int times, char *result) {

   for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      *(result + i) = c;
   }

   return result;
}
```

As you can probably tell I am trying to repeat the `c` `times` times and store the result in the string `result` (a char pointer).

I am invoking it like this:

```
char *result = "";
repeat_char('o', 3, result); // hoping for "ooo"
```

But all I get is a nasty:

```
RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time: 160ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

I am really puzzled. Anyone? Thanks

Comment: `*(result + i)` is better expressed as `result[i]`.

Comment: Try `char result[42] = "";
repeat_char('o', sizeof result - 1, result);`

Comment: Also `repeat_char` needs to ensure the resulting string is NUL terminated with `result[i] = '\0'`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I'd leave this to the caller. Not each `char`-array is meant to serve as a "string".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart; That's not necessary if it is not used in a function which expects a pointer to a null terminated string.

Comment: BTW, doing `memset(result, c, times);` instead of the loop is at least less typing ... ;-)

Comment: $20 says the OP will call `printf("result: %s\n", result);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are trying to change to a string literal which are *non-modifiable*. That's why you get the error. It's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

- Either allocate dynamically allocated memory and pass pointer to it Or -
- simply pass a char array which is not string literal.

*Make sure the passed string is big enough to hold the result.(along with `'\0'`)* It is not mandatory. You can have a char array without terminating `NUL` but then you can't use it in standard string function which expects `NUL` terminated char array.

Solution is to use something like

```
char *result = malloc(10);
// check the return value of malloc.
// if result is not NULL pass it.
```

or

```
char result[10];
```

Also don't forget to put the `'\0'` (For the reason stated above).

#### Even if string literal was mutable..

Well then also it would get you segmentation fault trying to access the array index out of bound.

`char *str = ""` is basically pointing to a single element array which conatins `\0`  and that array is basically decayed into pointer to the first element of the array namely a `char` and being assigned to `str`. So you have only `1` element there and you *can't* put `3` characters with `\0` there.

<sup>**Segmentation fault** meaning you are accessing some memory which you shouldn't.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

In C, string literals shall not be modified. Any attempt to modify a string literal will result in undefined behavior. Instead of a string literal you can have an array of char of size `times`.

Change

```
char *result = "";
```

to

```
char result[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Header.h**

```
#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE               0
#endif

#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE                1
#endif

char *repeat_char(const char c, int times);
```

**function.c**

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    const char  star = 42;
    printf("%s\n",repeat_char(star,5));
}

char *repeat_char(const char c, int times) 
{
    int     i;
    int     useLoop =   FALSE;  // TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0
    char    *result =   (char*)calloc(times+1, sizeof(char));

    printf("%i\n",strlen(result));
    printf("'%s'\n", result);

    if (useLoop == TRUE)
    {
       for (i = 0; i < times; i++) 
       {
            result[i] = c;
            printf("%i\n",strlen(result));
            printf("'%s'\n", result);
       }
    }
    else
       memset(result, c, times);
    
    printf("%i\n",strlen(result));
    printf("'%s'\n", result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can flip the useLoop flag to FALSE to test with the loop, however, I prefer the memset instead.  Obviously remove the printf statements, as well as, the if statement and loop (unless you prefer the loop -- then get rid of the memset) before finalizing code and deploying.